# NSDateformatter added in Interface Builder on NSTextfield adds GMT difference

Tags: xcode, cocoa, binding, nsdateformatter, nstextfield

OK, I want to build a countdown timer with a `NSTextfield` and a `NSStepper` to increase it. 
Both have bindings to the same int property in `ModelKeyPath` in Interface `Builder`. To format the int value output to 00:00:00, I added a `NSDateFormatter` in `IB` to the `NSTextfield`.

It's working, but when I run the application, the difference to GMT in my case +001 is added.
The int value should be 0, but the textField shows 01:00:00

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    self.countdownTimer = [[Timer alloc] init];

    [self.countdownTimer setTimerCount:0];
}
```

I've done it programatically with this solution: [Convert Seconds Integer To HH:MM, iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739383/convert-seconds-integer-to-hhmm-iphone)
but i want to use the `NSDateFormatter`. Help appreciated.

Comment: set the formatter's timezone to be your current timezone

Comment: Thx for the quick answer, so i have to set the NSDateformatter  programatically, because i have no option to do that in Inspector?

Comment: there is a relative date checkbox, but i really don't know what that does.. you can make one pretty easily, in `-awakeFromNib` just make a formatter, and add to the field with `-addFormatter:`

Comment: You can create an outlet for the date formatter and set the time zone in `-awakeFromNib`.

Comment: @GradyPlayer, would you make that an answer?

Comment: @noa thx for the hint :) I created an outlet timerFormatter from the NSDateFormatter and set it with:    `[_timerFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];`    in applicationDidFinishLaunching method.

Comment: @noa, you can make yours one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the formatter's time zone to be your current time zone.

There isn't a way to do that in IB, but you can create an outlet for the date formatter and set the time zone in `-awakeFromNib`.