# How to format time with NSDateFormatter like this HH:mm:ss

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I have the duration of a song in seconds.

After following calculations, I have the time in hour, minutes and seconds.

```
int hour = time / 3600;
int minute = (time / 60) % 60;
int second = time % 60;
```

I need to show them with this format HH:mm:ss

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you just want to show it as text on a label/ UIView?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739383/convert-seconds-integer-to-hhmm-iphone

Comment: like most of the answers point out, a NSDateFormatter isn't needed for what you ask

Comment: can't you show it like this: NSLog(@"Final OutPut>> %02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be helpful

```
- (NSString *)timeFormatted:(int)totalSeconds
{

    int seconds = totalSeconds % 60; 
    int minutes = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60; 
    int hours = totalSeconds / 3600; 

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d",hours, minutes, seconds]; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You needn't to use a NSDateFormatter according to your description

```
int hour = time / 3600;
int minute = (time / 60) % 60;
int second = time % 60;

NSString *yourDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second, null];
```

Comment: Does it make the correct format for all of cases?

Comment: yes : '%02d' display a int with at least two digits, adding '0' before if necessary : 0 becomes '00', 1 becomes '01', ... when the number is greater than 9 it remains unchanged

Answer (score 2):

This will append 0 and make it exactly 2 characters..

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d",hour,minute,second ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
int hour = time / 3600;
int minute = (time / 60) % 60;
int second = time % 60;

 NSString *dateStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %d %d",hour,minute,second];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *date1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Why create a date from the string? Not to mention that the date format you gave doesn't match the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%d:%d", hour, minute, second];
```

Comment: %02d should be used instead of %d

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
   float seconds = totalSeconds % 60; 
   float minutes = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60; 
   float hours = totalSeconds / 3600; 
   return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02f:%02f:%02f",hours, minutes, seconds];
```

Comment: seconds, minutes and hours should be integers not float