# How to get timezone offset as ±hh:mm?

Tags: swift, swift3, timezone

I can get the offset seconds from GMT with this: `TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT()`.

However, how do I get the format as `±hh:mm`?

Comment: Just get it using dateFormatter. `dateFormatter.dateFormat = "xxxxx"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Seconds Integer To HH:MM, iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739383/convert-seconds-integer-to-hhmm-iphone)

Comment: @LeoDabus You can't achieve this with `DateFormatter`. There's no `Date`.

Comment: @rmaddy `dateFormatter.string(from: Date())` would return `"-02:00"` for me

Comment: @LeoDabus But there's no Date here, just a time zone.

Comment: @rmaddy all he needs to do is get it from current date. He can also set the dateFormatter to a different timeZone if he wants to. `TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")`  would return "+00:00"

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Some integer arithmetic to obtain the offset in hours and
minutes:

```
let seconds = TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT()

let hours = seconds/3600
let minutes = abs(seconds/60) % 60
```

Formatted printing:

```
let tz = String(format: "%+.2d:%.2d", hours, minutes)
print(tz) // "+01:00"
```

`%.2d` prints an integer with (at least) two decimal digits (and leading
zero if necessary). `%+.2d` is the same but with a leading `+` sign for
non-negative numbers.

Comment: @Himanshujamnani: `TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT()` is the UTC offset.

Comment: why are you hard coding "+"?.

If it is "-01:00", it will print the same?

Comment: @ammateja: `+` in the `%+.2d` format prepends a plus sign only to positive numbers (and zero). Negative numbers are still printed with a leading minus sign.

Comment: Perfect solution, It's working for me.

Answer (score 11):

**Here is extension for getting timezone offset Difference and as ±hh:mm** (**Swift 4 | Swift 5 Code**)

```
extension TimeZone {

    func offsetFromGMT() -> String
    {
        let localTimeZoneFormatter = DateFormatter()
        localTimeZoneFormatter.timeZone = self
        localTimeZoneFormatter.dateFormat = "Z"
        return localTimeZoneFormatter.string(from: Date())
    }

    func offsetInHours() -> String
    {
    
        let hours = secondsFromGMT()/3600
        let minutes = abs(secondsFromGMT()/60) % 60
        let tz_hr = String(format: "%+.2d:%.2d", hours, minutes) // "+hh:mm"
        return tz_hr
    }
}
```

**Use like this**

```
print(TimeZone.current.offsetFromGMT()) // output is +0530
print(TimeZone.current.offsetInHours()) // output is "+05:30"
```

Comment: FYI: UTC != GMT.  GMT is a TimeZone, UTC is a corrected time adjusted from UT1.  Not the same at all.

Answer (score 8):

If you can use `Date()`

```
func getCurrentTimezone() -> String {
    let localTimeZoneFormatter = DateFormatter()
    localTimeZoneFormatter.dateFormat = "ZZZZZ"
    return localTimeZoneFormatter.string(from: Date())
}
```

Will return "+01:00" format

Comment: 5 Zs! 'Attaboy!

Comment: This is the way to do it. Don't do date math yourself if the OS will do it for you. (But note that you should set the formatter's time zone, if appropriate.)

Answer (score 2):

```
extension TimeZone {
    
    func offsetFromUTC() -> String
    {
        let localTimeZoneFormatter = DateFormatter()
        localTimeZoneFormatter.timeZone = self
        localTimeZoneFormatter.dateFormat = "Z"
        return localTimeZoneFormatter.string(from: Date())
    }
    
 
    func currentTimezoneOffset() -> String {
      let timeZoneFormatter = DateFormatter()
      timeZoneFormatter.dateFormat = "ZZZZZ"
      return timeZoneFormatter.string(from: Date())
  }
}


Use like this

print(TimeZone.current.offsetFromUTC()) // output is +0530
print(TimeZone.current.currentTimezoneOffset()) // output is "+05:30"
```

it working 100% in all countries according to timezone.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4 and above**

```
extension TimeZone {

    func timeZoneOffsetInHours() -> Int {
        let seconds = secondsFromGMT()
        let hours = seconds/3600
        return hours
    }
    func timeZoneOffsetInMinutes() -> Int {
        let seconds = secondsFromGMT()
        let minutes = abs(seconds / 60)
        return minutes
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer does not handle the case "-00:30" correctly since the "+/-" is only being determined from the hours, and not the minutes. I would set the sign based on a check of the initial seconds value. Alternatively you could use `DateComponentsFormatter`.

```
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
formatter.unitsStyle = .positional
formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
let interval: TimeInterval = TimeInterval.init(abs(secondsOffset))
let offsetValue: String = formatter.string(from: interval)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).